# Midi Sheet Music can no longer access the stored midi files since the Android 14 system update

Tags: audio, storage, files, music, android-14

The app [Midi Sheet Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.midisheetmusic) can no longer access the stored midi files on my Z Fold 4 since the Android 14 system update.

I had no problems accessing  with Android 13 or earlier. Short of rooting (which would void my warranty), are there any workarounds? I tried downloading Google Files after Fx didn't work.  No luck with native Samsung picker either.  Please help.

Comment: For reference the original app author open-sourced an early version of the app which has been taken up by others, github repo: https://github.com/ditek/MidiSheetMusic-Android, however based on: https://github.com/ditek/MidiSheetMusic-Android/pull/27 it still hasn't been released to F-Droid due to the storage permission behavior: https://github.com/ditek/MidiSheetMusic-Android/pull/27#issuecomment-1646606324